# DidSelectItemAtIndexPath not called for UITableView inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

My `self.view` has a `UIScrollView` as a subview. This `UIScrollView` has a container `UIView`, which holds many `UITableView`'s as subviews. These subviews are all configured using autolayout constraints.

So basically my scrollview is horizontally scrollable. I also have `UILongPressGesture` inside my `UIScrollView`.

My problem is `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` is not called while tapping over the cells inside `UITableView`. I have set `cancelTouchesInView` to `NO` for my `UILongPressGesture` but still `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` doesn't get called.

I don't want to add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to my `UIScollView` and manually trigger `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` , since I'm doing some operations in `UITableView` delegate methods.

How can I make my `UITableView` to responds to all of its delegate methods ?

Comment: have you confirmed to delegate protocol?

Comment: Yes I have set my UITableViewController as my delegate and also have implemented delegates. This UITableViewController works fine by calling delegates when pushed with navigation controller. Problem arises only when this UITableViewController's view is added as subview inside my container (which is inturn added as subview to UIScrollview).